# Problems with generic views using Coltrane blog template

Tags: django, django-views

I'm following the example for coltrane (a django blog) in James Bennett's Practical Django Projects to try to give me a starting point for my own custom blog.  I was able to do most of the work in the first chapter to get my blog all lined up, but when he switches to generic views it seems to break.

My blog works when I use the following views.py:

```
def entry_list(request):
    return render_to_response('blog/entry_listing.html',
                              { 'entry_list': Entry.objects.all() },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def entry_detail(request, year, month, day, slug):
    date_stamp = time.strptime(year+month+day, "%Y%b%d")
    publish_date = datetime.date(*date_stamp[:3])
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, publish_date__year=publish_date.year,
                              publish_date__month=publish_date.month,
                              publish_date__day=publish_date.day,
                              slug=slug)
    return render_to_response('blog/entry_detail.html',
                              { 'entry': entry },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py:

```
entry_info_dict = {
    'queryset': Entry.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'publish_date',
    }

urlpatterns = patterns('',
('^blog/$','blog.views.entry_list'),
('^blog/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','django.views.generic.date_based.object_detail',entry_info_dict),)
```

using these I can create a list of blog entries (using the first urlpattern) and then enter a 'detail view' to see the full entry (using the second url pattern).

Then it is suggested that I swap my urls.py to use a generic view to show the main blog listing, so my url.py becomes:

```
entry_info_dict = {
    'queryset': Entry.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'publish_date',
    }

urlpatterns = patterns('',
('^blog/$', 'django.views.generic.date_based.archive_index', entry_info_dict),
('^blog/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','django.views.generic.date_based.object_detail',entry_info_dict),)
```

I make the corresponding changes in my template (create a entry_archive.html, because this generic view defaults to a _archive.html template, and make sure that it uses the generic 'object' rather than 'entry' as the reference), but nothing shows up.

The template is:

entry_archive.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<p>These are public blog entries.</p>

<ul>
  {% for object in object_list %}
  {% if object.status == object.LIVE_STATUS %}

  {% include "blog/entry_summary.html" %}

  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

entry_summary.html

```
<div class="blog_entry">
  <h2 class="blog_title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
  <div class="blog_date">Published on {{ object.publish_date }}</div>
  <div class="blog_summary">{{ object.summary }}</div>
  <div class="blog_image"></div>
  <div class="blog_url"><a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">Read full entry</a></div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on what's not going quite right?

Comment: I'm using django version 1.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer -- the problem was that the archive_index generic view returns an object called 'latest' with all of the entries, and NOT an object called 'object_list'!